# Unordered_map find const wchar_t*

Tags: c++, find, unordered-map

I usethe following code to get a filename from an filepath:

```
const wchar_t* MyClass::PathFindFileNameW(const wchar_t* path)
{

 const wchar_t* p1 = path ? wcsrchr(path, L'\\') : nullptr;
 const wchar_t* p2 = path ? wcsrchr(path, L'/') : nullptr;

 p1 = !p1 || (p2 && p2 > p1) ? p2 : p1;

 return (p1 ? p1 + 1 : path);

}
```

I also have the following unordered_map definition:

```
std::unordered_map<const wchar_t*,std::string> mymap = {
 {L"file1.doc","Author1"},
 {L"file2.doc","Author2"},
 {L"file3.doc","Author3"} };
```

Using the following code I want to get the author from the map by filename:

```
std::unordered_map<const wchar_t*,std::string>::const_iterator got = mymap.find(this->PathFindFileNameW(this->path));

if (got == mymap.end())
{

    Log("No result");

}
```

This code logs 'No result" even if the filename exists in the map. Something like:

```
std::unordered_map<const wchar_t*,std::string>::const_iterator got = mymap.find(L"file1.doc");
```

gives a result. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a map with pointers as keys, so you will only find a string if it’s stored at the same address as a key.

Use `std::wstring` as keys.